# Unable to connect to EC2 redmine

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server, redmine

I have a free tier of windows EC2 machine. I setup a Bitnami Redmine on this EC2 windows instance. I can access this instance from the server itself, but I am unable to access it from my local computer.

I am pretty sure I opened the correct port (TCP 80 for HTTP) for HTTP. My remote desktop session is working too, but the main page of redmine just can't be reached from any machine outside.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is a windows server firewall issue which blocks my access. After changing the rules in the windows server firewall, it solved the problem.